# fn:substringAfter() last occurence

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

Lets say I have some strings like: `"1", "1.2", "1.2.3", "12.13"...`

With JSTL for the first 2 elements it is easy to output the last number after the `.`:

`${fn:contains(myStr, '.') ? fn:substringAfter(myStr,'.') : myStr}`

But this method does not work with the other elements. From above elements I would wish to get `"1", "2", "3", "13"`.

Since this is only relevant to the formatting of the frontend I would not want to solve this in the Java-Part.

Is there a way to achieve this with the default libs, or should I create an own tag for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

`${fn:split(myStr, '.')[fn:length(fn:split(myStr.index, '.'))-1]}`

Comment: `myStr.index` : `.index` shoud not be here